# На сколько безопасно использовать хеш-сумму для проверки ключа симметричного шифрования?

Tags: безопасность, шифрование, хеширование

Предположим, у меня есть зашифрованные данные и ключ к ним. Если я введу неправильный ключ, то дешифратор выведет неправильные данные. Можно ли использовать хеш-сумму для проверки ключа шифрования, чтобы избежать таких ошибок? Вернее, на сколько это безопасно?

Заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Небезопасно и вот почему - Еве будет достаточно подобрать пароль по готовому хэшу, что сделать относительно нетрудно - есть ASIC, есть видеокарты, задача прекрасно параллелится.

Для проверки того, что данные расшифровались, надо хэшировать данные и положить хеш в зашифрованный контейнер.

Тогда после расшифровки можно будет вычислить хэш и сравнить его с эталоном.